# jQuery: html() returning empty string

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I use firebug and type `$("<p>").html()` into the watch window, I get an empty string back. My guess is because the `$("<p>")` hasn't been rendered to the document. How can I get the markup for `$("<p>")` before it's added to the DOM?

Answer (score 6):

You're asking for the *outer* HTML, not the inner, the HTML *inside* the `<p>` is indeed empty.

To get the HTML you'd have to wrap it in another element, like this:

```
jQuery("<div>").append($("<p>").clone()).html()
```

This would give you:

```
<p></p>
```

Comment: Why `.clone()` a `$("<p>")` you just created? ;o)

Comment: @patrick - this is just an example...if used in practice, to not *move* the original element.

Comment: Nick - Yeah, I know. `$("p").clone()` to not move the original. But I don't imagine in practice there's ever a use for `.append($("<p>").clone())`. Was mostly just giving you a hard time.

Answer (score 2):

Try `$( 'p' ).html()` rather than `$( '<p>' ).html()`

Example at http://jsfiddle.net/tdg7U/

Test1 alerts `$( '<p>' ).html()`

Test2 alerts `$( 'p' ).html()`

Comment: It's probably worth including the tests in an answer here rather than relying on jsfiddle.